# Why do ASP elements in templates not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

In my ASPX file, I have an InsertItemTemplate inside of an ASP:formview. The template consists of a form made with asp:textbox, droplists, etc. The form is going to nothing but take the user input, pass it to a stored procedure on my SQL server and that will insert the data.

I've tested the SP separately, and it works fine. My problem is that the asp formviews and templates make no sense to me. It's like the data input in the fields doesn't exist so it's not passed to the SP so nothing is inserted. When I add the parameters to my codebehind, I am told it doesn't exist in the current context.

If I copy one of the textbox, completely unchanged, outside the formview, it magically now exists in the current context. Forgive my ignorance, but what's the point of an insert template if it can't actually pass info to be inserted?

Code (abbreviated for brevity):

```
<asp:FormView ID="PatientFormView"
            DataSourceID="Sqldatasource1"    
            Gridlines="Both" 
            runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" 
    HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="800">
...
Provider Name: <asp:TextBox ID="NPI" runat="server" Width="257px" Text='<%#Bind("npi")%>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:TextBox>
Patient MRN: <asp:TextBox ID="acctno" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="257px" Text='<%#Bind("acctno")%>'></asp:TextBox>

</InsertItemTemplate>
```

And then the codebehind:

```
protected void Sqldatasource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@NPI"].Value = NPI.Text.ToString();
    e.Command.Parameters["@acctno"].Value = acctno.Text.ToString();
}
```

That's where I get NPI and acctno do not exist in current context.

However, if I copy either of those asp texboxes out of the formview, they will exist. I suppose I could eliminate the entire template, but I want to understand this context issue.

Thanks in advance. I've tried to find an explanation for this, and most of what I find doesn't apply or refers to using the .design file, which I don't have on the pages in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `<%# Bind("...") %>` within the template, so you don't need to set the parameters manually. If you debug your `Sqldatasource1_Inserting` method, you'll notice that the parameters are already populated with the values from the bound controls.

The controls within the templates are not directly accessible from the code-behind because they might not be unique. For example, you might have a `TextBox` with an ID of "NPI" in both the `InsertItemTemplate` and the `EditItemTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't think I fully understand yet, but this helps. What I'm having a hard time getting is why, even after ensuring there aren't duplicate controls, can I not do something like     'Label1.Text = acctno.text.tostring();'  in the codebehind? I have been using javascript get to populate labels when I need them to pull something from one of the textboxes, but it seems ridiculous to have to do that. Again, I apologize for my ignorance, I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, and I'm managing but a bit more slowly than I'd prefer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @R_Scott: Even if you don't have any duplicate controls, the compiler won't generate a field for the controls in the template, just in case you add duplicates later. It would be pretty annoying if your code-behind stopped working as soon as you copied the `InsertItemTemplate` to the `EditItemTemplate`!

Comment: Good point.  Clearly I still have a lot of learning to do. I appreciate it.